# Regional restaurant disorder

Tags: discussion, tags

This is about 3 tags only a few questions are tagged with. I want to discuss whether they are needed or not.

---

1) [regional](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional)

Tag wiki excerpt:

> Used to tag questions that have region-specific content (e.g. specific legal issues, clothing sizes)

3 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional) are tagged [regional](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional). All are about the UK.

This seems to be a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that doesn't tell the viewer much, if anything at all. It doesn't make sense as a filter, also. In this case, it would be better to have special tags for the regions. And before introducing new ones, make sure it's needed (legal issues are off topic, clothing sizes - translate them into a more common one (like if you used US customary system, add metric system in brackets) - no need for an extra tag).

---

2) [restaurant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurant)

Tag wiki excerpt:

> Somewhere you go to eat food in public.

1 [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9133/how-to-eat-out-with-kids) is tagged [restaurant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurant).

It's almost exactly 5 years old, yet was never used again. This is just an example of [public-parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-parenting) and not really needed. Furthermore, the tag wiki excerpt does not fulfill the [site's standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/377968):

> The main purpose of the tag wiki excerpt is to **tell people what the tag should be used for.**

---

3) [disorder](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disorder)

No tag wiki excerpt.

10 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disorder) are tagged [disorder](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disorder).

The questions seem to cover all possible [meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disorder) of "disorder". This tag seems way too unspecific. Add a tag wiki excerpt or get rid of it entirely?

Comment: Thank you so much for this extraordinary job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree completely about the first and second tags being superfluous, and can be done away with.

The 'disorder' tag is probably usefully vague, and though it can be used in questions seeking medical advice (off topic), it can also just be a vague label used by a parent wondering but not knowing if their child has some kind of "disorder". Rather than having specific tags for sleep disorder, eating disorder, etc., I'm fine with a vague tag in this case. Just my $.02. But I'm fine with whatever the community desires.

Comment: I think I'm fine with disorder going away, as it doesn't really say anything - don't care a whole lot either though.

Comment: Tag *mental-health* may cover some of this already. For filtering purposes, specialized tags may be more useful, else you get combinations of tags like *eating* and *disorder* like [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22846/30519). But I'm not sure what is best.

Comment: @AnneDaunted - agree that disorder can allow funny pairings. My guess - and this isn't a great guess - is that if the tag was destroyed, someone would recreate it. But we won't know unless we try it. :)